# What does "party-speak" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does the author mean that their apologies were "too polite"?

> China’s rabidly nationalist netizens have even called for a boycott of Marriott. But more than losing business, foreign operators in China fear running foul of sweeping new cyber- and national-security laws. Among much else, these prohibit anything deemed to “damage national unity”. The apologies issued by some operators were **party-speak**. Marriott said, “We absolutely will not support any separatist organisation that will undermine China’s sovereignty and territorial integrity.” Delta airlines apologised for hurting the feelings of the Chinese people. Zara, a European fashion chain, even promised a “self-examination”.

18 Jan 2018 issue of [The Economist](https://www.economist.com/news/china/21735075-it-also-luring-its-people-china-getting-tougher-taiwan) "Banyan: China is getting tough on Taiwan"

Answer (score 23):

Party-speak refers to speech typical of a political party, in this case the Chinese Communist Party. The sense is of a language full of rigid and ritualistic formulations where the apologies are just a formality.

[The Arithmetic of Party-Speak](https://medium.com/@cmphku/the-arithmetic-of-party-speak-c52debdd41db):

> - The 19th National Congress of the Chinese Communist Party is just around the corner — and that means the machine of political discourse is humming away at high speed.

(Medium.com)

Here ***[speak](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/speak)*** is used as a suffix meaning:

> (informal mainly disapproving) used to form nouns to mean the special language used in a particular subject area or business:
>
> - computer-speak
> - marketing-speak

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 18):

Modern compounds ending in [*-speak*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/speak), though they echo the Middle English meaning as 'speech, language' (cf. German *Sprache*), derive from George Orwell's coinage *[Newspeak](https://www.etymonline.com/word/Newspeak)*, a heavily manipulated and manipulative language institutionalizing the authoritarian regime depicted in the novel *1984*. *Newspeak* was not merely the language *of* propaganda; it was crafted [“to make other modes of thought impossible.”](http://ecoglobe.ch/orwell/e/newspeak.htm#IMPOSSIBLE)

Coinages since the novel's publication in 1949 have incrementally reduced the meaning to designate a jargon which the speaker doesn't particularly like. Thus [dictionary.com defines](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/speak?s=t) such compounds as

> derogatory, derisive, or facetious, that denote the style or vocabulary of a discipline, person, era, etc., as specified by the initial element:
>   techspeak; artspeak; nukespeak; leetspeak; geek-speak.

I would submit that the word *party-speak* in reference to the People's Republic of China, hardly a free democracy, still carries some of the original Orwellian weight. So, for instance, a critique of a Party [program to inculturate ethnic minorities](https://cpianalysis.org/2016/03/08/learning-party-speak-what-the-new-textbook-for-dislocated-minority-students-tells-us-about-china/) depicts it as teaching *party-speak* along with Mandarin and the dominant Han culture.[image: Graphic from the textbook]

In their “apologies,” Western firms have used the same language to assure the Party that they have no desire to create any social or political disturbance — with a deference that seems strangely obsequious to Western ears.